# Powershell -Replace command and escaping characters

Tags: powershell

I need to replace some strings multiple text files. I am running into an issue with the following string though. I tried escaping with a backtick ` before any special characters, but no luck, or maybe the backtick isn't in the right place.

I want to replace

```
Signal\s+:\s+',''
```

with

```
Signal\s+:\s+','';if (!`$signal) {`$signal='n/a'}
```

This is the string in the command that i am having a problem finding --> Signal\s+:\s+',''

Here is the powershell command i am using..

```
Get-ChildItem "f:\temp\*.ps1" | ForEach-Object -Process {(Get-Content $_) -Replace "Signal\s+:\s+',''" , "Signal\s+:\s+','';if (!`$signal) {`$signal='n/a'}" | Set-Content $_}
```

thank you

Comment: Are you looking for the _literal string_ `Signal\s+:\s+',''`? If so, you need to escape the embedded regex metacharacters: `... -replace $([regex]::Replace('Signal\s+:\s+'',''''')), '...'`

Comment: I have a powershell script with the following line in it  -->           $signal=(netsh wlan show interfaces) -Match '^\s+Signal' -Replace '^\s+Signal\s+:\s+',''      I want to replace this line with this -->      $signal=(netsh wlan show interfaces) -Match '^\s+Signal' -Replace '^\s+Signal\s+:\s+',''; if (!$Signal) {$Signal='n/a'}

Answer (score 0):

i just needed to escape the \ in the replace text.. thats all

```
-Replace "Signal\\s\+:\\s\+',''"
```

thanks